# Stopping Android Tabs Refreshing When Clicking On The Next Fragment Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, refresh, android-tabs

I have a problem with my fragment tabs. In Android, they are programmed to refresh when clicking on the tab that is either two to the right or two to the left from the current tab. All of these tabs will be quickly accessed and have data that shouldn't be refreshed. Does anybody know how I can force it to not refresh the fragment tabs?

Thanks in advance.